# Border-bottom 1px too long on both sides CSS

Tags: html, css

**What I am doing:**
On hover of a button I am addding a border-bottom of 5px.

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/mUCNB/

**Problem:**

The problem is the border bottom extends 1px too far on both the left and right side.

[image]

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Relevant Code:**

```
#main-nav li a {
display: block;
padding-top: 15px;
text-align: center;
height: 35px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 18px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #00a0c8;
}

#main-nav li a:first-child, #main-nav li a:nth-child(2) {
width: 224px;
border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#main-nav li a:nth-child(3) {
width: 225px;
}

#main-nav li a:last-child {
width: 224px;
border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#main-nav  a:hover {
height: 30px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #0BC6F5;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mUCNB/

Comment: CSS borders 'miter' at the edge, coming together at an angle. What you are seeing is a result of that.

Comment: experimenting with border-radius-left: 1px and border-radius-right: 1px may help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CSS borders 'miter' at the edges, you're going to notice that phenomenon. To work around this, I've created rules to highlight the `li` BEHIND the `a` that is on hover. This creates the effect that you are getting a clean border at the bottom. You can retain those white separators between your elements too then.

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh2mp/2/)

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

#header {
  background-color: #00a0c8;
  min-height: 118px;
}

#headerContent {
  width: 980px;
  min-height: 118px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #00a0c8;
}

nav {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav li {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff; /* Added border to nav li */
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 50px; /* Give it height */
}

#main-nav li:hover {
  background: #0BC6F5; /* Give background color to li on hover */
}

nav li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

#main-nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #00a0c8;
}

#main-nav li a:first-child, #main-nav li a:nth-child(2) {
  width: 224px;
}

#main-nav li a:nth-child(3) {
  width: 225px;
}

#main-nav li a:last-child {
  width: 224px;
}

#main-nav li a:hover {
  height: 30px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this issue by removing the border-left and border-right styles from the following:

updated css:

```
#main-nav li a:first-child, #main-nav li a:nth-child(2) {
width: 224px;
}

#main-nav li a:last-child {
width: 224px;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUCNB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Also a neat trick is to just use box-shadow instead, to apply the conflicting border:

```
#main-nav  a:hover {
height: 30px;
box-shadow:0 5px 0 -1px #0BC6F5;
}
```

This works, if you just replace your current hover selector!

if you want to try it first, here's another fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4zzMA/

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this too! Nice job.